# How to add multiple rules using jquery widgets?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery widgets to validate the form. I am able to add only one rule for one id but i want to add multiple rules and message. I am doing code in asp.net. I am adding multiple rules like this.

```
 $('#form1').jqxValidator({ rules: [
                    { input: '#txtUserName', message: 'Your username must be between 3 and 12 characters!', action: 'keyup', rule: 'length=3,12' },
                    { input: '#txtUserName', message: 'Username is required!', action: 'keyup, blur', rule: 'required' },
                    { input: '#txtPassword', message: 'Invalid e-mail!', action: 'keyup', rule: 'email'}],
                theme: 'summer'
            });
```

But it is showing only one message, please help me to add multiple rules and message.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Can you please verify if ids are unique?

Comment: Yes, Ids are fine because first rule is working on id but the second is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Change the order of validation for `txtUserName`, put required first and then length validation.

```
$('#form1').jqxValidator({ 
    rules: [
        { input: '#txtUserName', message: 'Username is required!', action: 'keyup,blur', rule: 'required' },
        { input: '#txtUserName', message: 'Your username must be between 3 and 12 characters!', action: 'keyup', rule: 'length=3,12' },
        { input: '#txtPassword', message: 'Invalid e-mail!', action: 'keyup', rule: 'email'}],
    theme: 'summer'
});
```

**Note** : You can see validation message for one rule at a time. 
When you enter some text in username which fails `length` validation then you can see the `length` message and if you delete entered text completely then both (`required` and `length`) validation fails but you can see only required message as `required` has precedence on `length` validation.

[Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQwmm/81/)